# Display Android Bluetooth Device Name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, device-name

How to display a bluetooth device name in android which uses Java? Any codes for me to refer to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The below code will get u the bluetooth name, here `mBluetoothAdapter` is of type `BluetoothAdapter`.

```
  public String getLocalBluetoothName(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
    String name = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
    if(name == null){
        System.out.println("Name is null!");
        name = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hussain! It works well with my code. But if I were to retrieve the handset address also works the same way?

Comment: `import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),secure.ANDROID_ID);` this will be useful to get the unique id for the android device

Comment: @TunA:`TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();` Activity class. getDeviceID() will return the MDN or MEID of the device depending on which radio the phone uses (GSM or CDMA).

Comment: but then it will be the serial number of the android device that I'm retrieving not the handset address of the bluetooth device that I had connected it to the PC.. Is there any way that you can explain to me clearly?

Comment: U need the address if the Bluetooth device?

Comment: I need the address of the handset device by using bluetooth that is being plugged into my PC.. Can I ask what other information can I show using Bluetooth?

Comment: I think the `mAdapter.getAddress()` will do for u. U better go thro this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html

Comment: It works fine! Thank you Hussain! Does it works the same way if I want to retrieve the Bluetooth version?

Comment: Ya u can also take the bluetooth version from that itself.

Comment: Remember <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />