# how would you give name to bluetooth service in android things?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things

I created one simple service in android things to use Bluetooth BLE.when I try to test it with NRF connect app it's visible as "unknown service".I want to give name something like "Speed Service".how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a factor controlled by the scanning app you are using, not necessarily your Android Things device. Bluetooth LE doesn't send metadata like a "service name" over the air. Services are identified by their UUID alone. If your device implements one of the [standard service UUIDs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services), a scanner app like NRF Connect will ***probably*** recognize and display the service type.

As another example, our [Bluetooth GATT Server](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver) sample implements the standard **Current Time Service** by using the UUID adopted by the Bluetooth SIG for that service.

Answer (score 1):

```
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

void ChangeDeviceName(){
                Log.i(LOG, "localdevicename : "+bluetoothAdapter.getName()+" localdeviceAddress : "+bluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
                bluetoothAdapter.setName("NewDeviceName");
                Log.i(LOG, "localdevicename : "+bluetoothAdapter.getName()+" localdeviceAddress : "+bluetoothAdapter.getAddress());
            }
```

Reference: [Change the Android bluetooth device name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377558/change-the-android-bluetooth-device-name)

Hope this case is similar and of use to you.

Comment: I want to name the service in android things.service which runs on the raspberry pi or in other similar circuits.