# How to change Bluetooth name programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying to change my Bluetooth name but it did not work on all devices

old devices where we used to change the Bluetooth name from Bluetooth settings worked in my case. while the new devices that have a Device name used for all connectivity as same common name it did not work although it returns true but nothing changed

```
myBluetoothAdapter.setName("new name");
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377558/change-the-android-bluetooth-device-name

Comment: @shizhen as I said it works for old devices example sonny z2 while it did not work on my note 8