# Accessing 'Device Name' in Android 4.2 devices

Tags: android

From Android 4.2 onwards, user can change the Device name in settings menu. Is there any API exposed to retrieve that value from code??

[image]

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662216/display-android-bluetooth-device-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can rely on this functionality as it may be a Samsung modification.

My Nexus 5 does not have the ability to change the device name on this settings page on Android 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, use this:

```
android.os.Build.MODEL
```

to get the model,and this to get the manufacturer:

```
android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
```

**UPDATE:** As been said here, No all device will have this option.
You can try getting it this way:

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
String deviceName = myDevice.getName();
```

add a perrmision to the manifest file as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

reference: [How do you get the user defined "Device Name" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704597/how-do-you-get-the-user-defined-device-name-in-android)

But this wont always work.

Comment: No..I need Device name set by user. MODEL and MANUFACTURER is different.

Answer (score 0):

To display the device name/model in android use:

```
     TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
     String str = android.os.Build.MODEL;
     tv1.setText(str);
```

Comment: i have not seen your answer.